# Different Representations of Data in 1 View Controller

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I am using Xcode 6 and Swift.

I have some data that I'd like to represent in two or three different ways using a segmented control.

The first view is a list, the second is a grid, and the third is a table with some labels.

Despite the different appearances, they are all drawing from the same data source.

What is a sensible way to achieve this?

Should I drag 3 views onto 1 controller (the same view controller), and do all of my design/storyboarding within each view, add constraints as needed, and then just show/hide each view accordingly?

Is there a different or better way to do this, or is this about right?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the requirement, i feel TabViewController is best. Using segmented controller you need to take care of switching views yourself. You can have a TabViewController with 3 viewControllers and these view controllers can draw waterer data they need from your data source.

Comment: thanks - what if I was already using TabViewController, for something else (higher level, more hierarchical/organizational)? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two elegant ways to this effectively and clearly.

1)You can use different `xib` for each 3 views and on runtime load appropriate `xib` of the different views.This approch should used if you have small and clear views.There is not much work need to handle like `dataSource` and `delgations`.The three views will manage by only one view controller.**It will make all your views separate and easily managable**.You can load diffrent views as

```
//Your view property
var uiview :UIView?
//load nib from bundle in view    
self.uiview = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
```

2)Use `container viewcontroller`.By doing this you can add the different controllers to your parent controller.This approach is very clean as different views are handled by differnt controllers but it is hard to write.Use this if you have heavy work need to do by each view.See WWDC video to get more help https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102

I think in your case `1st` approach is appropriate use the three different xib and load it on runtime and add as `subview` of your `viewController`

Comment: Thank you - and forgive my ignorance, but is xib an antiquated thing generally not used anymore in Xcode (or something used before storyboards) or is xib a fundamental thing one would expect even with Swift?

Comment: Oh also, is there anything wrong with me just using the segmented control to just take the user to 3 different view controllers? There would be some code duplication maybe 5-10 lines here and there.